# check if multidimensional array is jagged?

Tags: vb.net, jagged-arrays, multidimensional-array

Does vb.net have a built-in function to check if a multidimensional array of unknown shape from a user passed as a `Function` parameter is jagged?  If so, what is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues here.  Multidimensional arrays (defined like `Integer(,)`) are never "jagged".  You can detect this by checking the array's [Rank](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.rank.aspx).  The [`GetLowerBound`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.getlowerbound.aspx) and [`GetUpperBound`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.getupperbound.aspx) methods can be used to check the length of the individual dimensions as needed.

If you are looking to see if a Jagged array (ie: `Integer()()`) is fully initialized, and each sub array is the same length (ie: determine whether a jagged array is "logically" rectangular), you could use something like:

```
Dim initializedToSameLengths As Boolean
If theArray(0) Is Nothing Then
   ' If first element is null, check for all others being null
   initializedToSameLengths = theArray.All(Sub(a) a = Nothing)
Else
   Dim firstLength = theArray(0).Length
   initializedToSameLengths = theArray.All(Sub(a) a <> Nothing AndAlso a.Length = firstLength)
End If
```

Comment: ty for `(,)` "never 'jagged'"! (as that's how i'm initializing 2d in `WebMethod`)

Answer (score 1):

If the array is multidimensional, it will have more than 1 dimension (so the `Array.Rank` property will be `>1`). If the array is jagged, it will be a one-dimensional array with arrays as elements (so its `Array.Rank` property will be `=1`).

Comment: Note that Array.Rank being one can also be a single dimensional, non-jagged array.